# Homogeneous polynomials minoration

Tags: polynomials

I am faced with a result I cannot seem to prove, even though my teacher said it is elementary.

If $P[X_1, ..., X_n]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ that can only have $0$ as a root, then there exists $C>0$ such that for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $|P(\xi)|\geqslant C|\xi|^d$

This seems reasonable when looking at $1D$ examples but I cannot seem to find the idea to prove it in the general case.

Thanks to all !

Comment: Hint: consider the minimum of $|P|$ on the sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this is it !

The function $\xi\mapsto |P(\xi)|$ is continuous on the sphere which is compact. Furthermore, this function does not have any zero on the sphere. Thus, its infimum (and even minimum) $C$ is positive and if $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$,
$|P(\dfrac{\xi}{\Vert \xi\Vert}))|\geqslant C$ and with $P$ being $d$-homogeneous, we have the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add the answer to this post and accept it.

The function $\xi\mapsto\vert P(\xi)\vert$ is continuous on the sphere which is compact (finite dimension context). Furthermore, this function does not have any zero on the sphere. Thus, its infimum (and even minimum) $C$ is positive and if $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}, \vert P(\frac{\xi}{\Vert\xi\Vert})\vert\geqslant C$ (if $\xi=0$, we have the inequality as the right-hand side is $0$). As $P$ is d-homogeneous, we thus have
$$
\begin{equation}
\vert P(\xi)\vert\geqslant C\Vert\xi\Vert^d
\end{equation}
$$
for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d$.